# How to limit rows in oracle select queries

Tags: database, node-oracledb

I want to get the first 10 table Rows in USER database client table in oracle database 21c.how to write the query for it...
I use,   `Select * from client LIMIT 10;`
it not worked.

I use,   `Select * from client LIMIT 10;`
for get first 10 table rows in client table,
but it not worked(not give any output).

Comment: What do you mean by it not worked ?

Comment: The node-oracledb documentation explains how to do it: [Limiting Rows and Creating Paged Datasets](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#limiting-rows-and-creating-paged-datasets) and points to a runnable example [rowlimit.js](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/examples/rowlimit.js).

Answer (score 2):

There is no `LIMIT` clause in Oracle SQL

Option 1:

```sql
select * from client fetch first 10 row only
```

Option 2:

```sql
select * from client where rownum <= 10
```

Comment: I would remove the second option, since it was useful before Oracle 12c. All those Oracle versions are now unsupported.